# htaccess redirect homepage to subdirectory keep url the same

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to get my `.htaccess` to redirect just the homepage URL to a sub directory (domain.com > domain.com/sub/sub ), but I still want the URL to display as domain.com.

I looked around for the past hour and have tried a number of suggestions that I found but nothing worked out.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /sub/sub [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply that part worked out great but I still need to be able to keep the the domain at domain.com. Possible?

Comment: This is what I have so far: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^$ sub/sub [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`